# WPFToolkit.Aero2 failed to load

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, xceed

I get this error when debugging:
Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' : 'The assembly with display name 'WPFToolkit.Aero2' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WPFToolkit.Aero2, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I tried uninstall the Extended WPF Toolkit nuget (3.3.0) and install again. didn't solve.

What am I missing ?

- I am using VS Enterprise 2017 version 15.5.7, .NET 4.7.1.
- The exception is when I debug Managed debugging assistant on the upper
  line of my Xaml.
- My references are:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just had the same issue, while using the WPFToolkit.Extended (standalone, old version)

fixed it by removing the reference I had, and installing the nuget you refer to.

my current references look like this:

[image]

Note, that I **don't** reference "**WPFToolkit**", while you - do.
I would say, try removing the "WPFToolkit" reference, see if it helps.